# Combining rows into 1 and totalling the amounts

Tags: sql

I have written the below script but unfortunately have become stuck.
Currently it reads

```
SELECT dim1        AS Costc,
       period      AS Period,
       sum(actual) AS Beds,
       CASE
         WHEN measure LIKE 'beds%' THEN ISNULL(sum(actual), 0)
       END         AS BEDS,
       CASE
         WHEN measure LIKE 'occu%' THEN ISNULL (sum(actual), 0)
       END         AS OCCU,
       measure
FROM   statistics
WHERE  measure IN (SELECT measure
                   FROM   statistics
                   WHERE  measure LIKE 'beds%'
                           OR measure LIKE 'occu%')
       AND dim1 = 'ABC'
       AND period = '201301'
GROUP  BY period,
          dim1,
          measure
```

which 
returns

```
COSTC | Period | Beds | BEDS | OCCU | Measure
 ABC  | 201301 |  40  |  40  | NULL | beds_abc
 ABC  | 201301 |  35  |  35  | NULL | beds_def
 ABC  | 201301 |  30  | NULL |  30  | occu_abc
 ABC  | 201301 |  20  | NULL |  20  | occu_def
```

My desired output is

```
COSTC | Period | BEDS | OCCU
 ABC  | 201301 |  75  |  50
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

Remove the `measure` from the `GROUP BY` and you need to move the aggregates outside the `CASE` expressions

```
SELECT dim1                AS Costc,
       period              AS Period,
       sum(actual)         AS Beds,
       isnull(SUM(CASE
                    WHEN measure LIKE 'beds%' THEN actual
                  END), 0) AS BEDS,
       isnull(SUM(CASE
                    WHEN measure LIKE 'occu%' THEN actual
                  END), 0) AS OCCU
FROM   statistics
WHERE  measure IN (SELECT measure
                   FROM   cukstats
                   WHERE  measure LIKE 'beds%'
                           OR measure LIKE 'occu%')
       AND dim1 = 'ABC'
       AND period = '201301'
GROUP  BY period,
          dim1
```

Comment: "measure" cannot be in the select list if it is not part of the group by.

Comment: @bleeeah - It isn't in the `SELECT` list. It is inside an aggregate. This is a normal `PIVOT` approach.

Comment: yeah that's fine for BEDS and OCCU, but it is still the final column being returned.

Comment: @bleeeah - I see your point! Thanks. (Offending item removed)